# Laravel remove copyright notice from mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, copyright-display

When sending mail over laravel, it will automatically append a gray "(c) 2019 Laravel. All rights reserved." on the bottom of the mail. Is there a way I can get rid of this? Here´s a picture of a sample mail: (created with `php artisan make:mail SampleMail --markdown="mail.sample"` and calling it over my controller) - Received over mailtrap.io
[image: Sample Mail received over mailtrap.io]
**Edit:** This copyright notice is not included in the markdown template created by the `make:mail` command.

Comment: Check the template where it is and remove it. You can use inspect tool also and then search via class or id

Comment: In the config/app.php change the name to your app name, or change it in the env file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out as well.  I love Laravel, but the mail thing is sometimes a bit hard to follow with the layers to dive through.

First, publish your own folder so you can edit the mail message within your own app:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

Once done, in your views folder there will be a

> vendor/mail

folder.  This contains the files you can alter.  There are a number of ways you can do this.  When you create a new mailable, the top line is going to pull in the **message** blade file as a component:

```
@component('mail::message', ['header_url' => $header_url, 'header_title' => $header_title])
```

This file is in your mail folder (either HTML or Markdown depending on how you've created it).  You can alter this permanently by changing the footer file it calls.  I just skipped the footer file and changed the base message file since it was always coming from the same place, and to reduce the Laravel clutter.  **You can remove it here** as well.  Here's what I did to change it:

```
{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
    @component('mail::footer')
        © {{ date('Y') }} {{ $companyName }}. All rights reserved.
    @endcomponent
@endslot
```

Comment: Very nice! I just noticed I would only have to change my app name in my .env-file, Can I just delete the vendor/ folder in my views folder or will I have to run some command to "unbind" it from any internal functions?

Comment: Okay, I deleted the vendor/mail directory and ran 'php artisan view:clear' and then deleted the vendor directory (all in the resources/views/ directory). Everything is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, and no, deleting wont be a problem.  But, you may wish to keep it there if you want to make any other altercations.  But, sounds like you're all set